# Media-related callbacks not invoked on Chrome sender

Tags: chromecast

I'm working on a custom sender & receiver for Chromecast, using a custom HTML5 player and communicating via the built-in media channel/namespace.

When sending a message from the sender to the receiver, e.g. session.loadMedia or media.pause, they are handled correctly on the receiver. However, in the sender, neither the success not the error callback are invoked. What would I be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see these events/callbacks happening correctly on the CastVideos-chrome sample app? If so, you may want to compare your app with what that app does.

Comment: haven't tried this one yet. will do so!

Comment: For the load event, I got it to work by using mediaManager.sendLoadComplete();

Is there a similar call for play and pause? I cannot get onSuccess for them.

Comment: If you are rolling out everything yourself, you need to listen to events on the Media Element; it has a whole bunch of events associated with various states of the playback, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following - they media element is on the receiver, I'm not getting callbacks for play & pause requests on the sender...